# Why there is error in importing clojure.spec.alpha?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm having a boot-clj project with the below dependencies,

```
 :dependencies   '[[org.clojure/clojure "RELEASE"]
                            [adzerk/boot-test "RELEASE" :scope "test"]]
```

Under that project, I'm running `boot repl` and trying to experiment with `clojure.spec`.

As a first step, I tried importing the required dependency using

`(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])`

While doing so, I'm getting the below error,

> ```
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/ident?
> ```
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:

What does it mean? And how to fix it?

Comment: This might help, https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Setting-Clojure-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed noting the below error when running `boot repl`,

> Classpath conflict: org.clojure/clojure version 1.8.0 already loaded,
>   NOT loading version 1.10.1

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018877/2046462), I had to add `boot.properties` with the content `BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.10.1` to get it resolved.

Clarifying that, its no wonder that spec didn't work in the above REPL, because spec expects Clojure 1.9.0 or higher.

And the reason of the error might be that `clojure.core/ident?` is not available in `1.8.0`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
[adzerk/boot-test "1.2.0"]
```

Using `"RELEASE"` instead of a concrete version number is problematic since it leads to non-repeatable builds.

I would also recommend occasional use of `lein-ancient` to notify you when the version of a dependency needs to be updated.

https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient

---

You can find more information here:

- [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution

Comment: "deprecated" implies this was previously a thing, but "RELEASE" (or "LATEST") has never been a supported feature of deps.edn as it prevents you from creating a fixed set of deps (and thus breaks the cache).

Comment: 'Deprecated' doesn't explain the reason of that error.